# How to specify to only match first occurrence?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I specify to only match the first occurrence of a regular expression in C# using Regex method?

Here's an example:

```
string text = @"<link href=""/_layouts/OracleBI/OracleBridge.ashx?RedirectURL=res/sk_oracle10/b_mozilla_4/common.css"" type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet""></link></link>";
string pattern = @"(<link).+(link>)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Match m = myRegex.Match(text);   // m is the first match
while (m.Success)
{
    // Do something with m
    Console.Write(m.Value + "\n");
    m = m.NextMatch();              // more matches
}
Console.Read();
```

I would like this to only replace up to the first `<\link>`. And then also do the same for the rest of these matches.

Comment: Do you want to use `Regex.Replace()`?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to first understand how to get the first occurrence and then next would like to find each match and replace. Example:

String str = "Hello this Hello Hello World";
String pattern = @"(H.+o)";
Regex re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
String result = re.Replace(str, "Replacement");

Result of str: Replacement this Hello Hello World
then:

I would like to replace all occurrences of Hello with Replacement (I tried womps example below but it did not work). The whole thing is that I need to use complex regexs rather than jus replacing Hello with Replacment

Comment: then:

I would like to replace all occurrences of Hello with Replacement (I tried womps example below but it did not work). The whole thing is that I need to use complex regexs rather than just replacing Hello with Replacement

Comment: @Josh - could you post the entire code by editing your question?  We can analyze it a bit better that way.

Comment: @Josh - agh... you're parsing HTML with Regex?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe you just need to add a lazy qualifier on the first example.  Whenever a wild card is "eating too much", you either need a lazy qualifier on the wild card or, in a more complicated scenario, look ahead.  Add a lazy qualifier at the top (`.+?` in place of `.+`), and you should be good.

Answer (score 47):

[Regex.Match(myString)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) returns the first match it finds.

Subsequent calls to `NextMatch()` on the resultant object from `Match()` will continue to match the next occurrences, if any.

For example:

```
  string text = "my string to match";
  string pattern = @"(\w+)\s+";
  Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

  Match m = myRegex.Match(text);   // m is the first match
  while (m.Success)
  {
       // Do something with m

       m = m.NextMatch();              // more matches
  }
```

---

EDIT: If you're parsing HTML, I would seriously consider using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).  You will save yourself many, many headaches.

Comment: this solution (with the addition of m = m.NextMatch();) still doesn't do the first match. Seems to find the last occurrence.

Comment: Here's an example:

string text = @"<link href=""/_layouts/OracleBI/OracleBridge.ashx?    RedirectURL=res/sk_oracle10/b_mozilla_4/common.css"" type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet""></link></link>";

string pattern = @"(<link).+(link>)";

Comment: Make sure you write **m =** `m.NextMatch()` in your loop or it will be infinite.

Comment: ... speaking of parsing HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/837703

Answer (score 3):

```
string text = @"<link href=""/_layouts/OracleBI/OracleBridge.ashx?RedirectURL=res/sk_oracle10/b_mozilla_4/common.css"" type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet""></link></link>"; 
string pattern = @"(<link).+(link>)"; 
//Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
//Match m = myRegex.Match(text);   // m is the first match
Match m = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
/*while (m.Success)         
{             
    // Do something with m             
    Console.Write(m.Value + "\n");             
    m = m.NextMatch();              // more matches         
}*/
// use if statement; you only need 1st match
if (m.Success)
{
    // Do something with m.Value
    // m.Index indicates its starting location in text
    // m.Length is the length of m.Value
    // using m.Index and m.Length allows for easy string replacement and manipulation of text
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Also Regex.Match(input, pattern, Regex Options) will shorten your code

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping combined with `RegExOptions.ExplicitCapture`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little over-simplified, but if you get a collection of matches back and want to get the first occurrence you could look at the `Match.Index` property to find the lowest index.

Here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match_members.aspx) on it.

If it is just a scope issue, then I agree with [Rich's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631183/c-regex-how-to-specify-to-only-match-first-occurrence/2631668#2631668) - you need to use non-greedy modifiers to stop your expression from 'eating' too much.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string text = @"<link href=""/_layouts/OracleBI/OracleBridge.ashx?RedirectURL=res/sk_oracle10/b_mozilla_4/common.css"" type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet"">      </link></link>";
string pattern = @"(<link).+(link>)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


MatchCollection matches = myRegex.Matches(text);
        foreach (Match m in matches) {
            Console.Write(m.Value + "\n");
        }
Console.Read();
```