# Regex to return only first result from multiple matches

Tags: c#, regex, match

Using `c# vs2008` Regex

I am trying to get a number from a very long string loaded from text from a file.

In this source string there are multiple instances of the data i want to get out.
Eg. "*Tax Invoice No          INV1870507*" may be repeated 10 times in the source `String`, with any unknown number of characters between each match.
I want to get the number "1870507" out. The number is different for every different file I load and I need to find what the number is.

Using this pattern : `(?<=Tax Invoice No[\s\r\n]+INV)(?'InvNo'[^\s\r\n]+)?`
I can correctly get a match on every occurance and can read the number.

But I get like 10 matches and 10 groups.

I want the `Regex` to short circuit at the first match and return only 1 match becasue then I have the info I need and there is no need to keep matching.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631183/c-sharp-regex-how-to-specify-to-only-match-first-occurrence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use this for C#, so you can just use:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=Tax Invoice No[\s\r\n]+INV)(?'InvNo'[^\s\r\n]+)?");
regex.Match(myString);
```

Match: Searches the input string for the **first occurrence** of a regular expression...

That should actually do what you want.