# Regex for finding first occurrence of price

Tags: regex

I need to extract just `94.00` from the string below.

Which regex would I use to do so? My current regex of `[^$]+$` is returning `$99.00 (176)`

```
5 Easy Payments $94.00 $99.00 (176)
```

Comment: `\$[\d.]+` .....

Comment: In what language? Some matching methods return just the first occurrence, some return all.

Comment: Please tell us *where* and how you are using the regex.

Comment: In C#, I'd use `Regex.Match(s, @"\d*\.?\d+").Value`, in Python, `re.search(r'\d*\.?\d+', s).group()`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's using .net version of regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify to only match first occurrence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631183/how-to-specify-to-only-match-first-occurrence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you might want to use this regular expression:

`\$[\d.]+`

This matches all prices, so depending on your language, juse use the function to get the first occurrence. However, this will also match something ridiculous like `$......` as a price.

`\$[\d]+\.[\d]+` will only match prices in the form `$123.456` with an arbitrary number of digits.

`^[^$]+\$[\d]+\.[\d]+` will match everything up to the last digit in the price. This is useless in its current state because it returns `5 Easy Payments $94.00` for your test string.

`^[^$]+(\$[\d]+\.[\d]+)` will match the same thing as above, but Group #1 of the regular expression will be the price `$94.00`. If you want to only match the number itself, move the left bracket over so it becomes `^[^$]+\$([\d]+\.[\d]+)`.

The issue is that this will return no matches if there's a non-price dollar sign somewhere before the first valid price. As long as that's not an issue, then `^[^\$]+\$([\d]+\.[\d]+)` will give you `94.00` for Capture Group 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a capturing mechanism if you cannot use any normal programming method to control the amount of matches you get:

```
/(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[\s\S]*/
```

This regex finds the first (because any regex engine processes the string from left to right, at least by default) `$`+`1 or more digits`+`an optional sequence of '.' and 1 or more digits`, *captures* this text into Group 1 (with `(\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`) and then *matches* and *consumes* the whole rest of the string with `[\s\S]*` (any 0 or more chars).

[Your value is in Group 1](https://regex101.com/r/RVnXWZ/1):

[image]